# Error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" when accessing a clearly existing, integer type data from Laravel Database query result

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, hashmap

I got my data from Laravel database query command:

```
$group = DB::table('groups')->where("id", $group_id)->first();
```

When I var dump my data, I get:

```
object(stdClass)#200 (7) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["levels_id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["title"]=>
  string(8) "Novice 1"
  ["description"]=>
  string(11) "Lorem Ipsum"
  ["max_question_display"]=>
  int(5)
  ["created_at"]=>
  NULL
  ["updated_at"]=>
  NULL
}
```

I want to access the `max_question_display`. But when I do:

```
var_dump($group["max_question_display"]);
```

PHP returns error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.

When I do:

```
var_dump($group->max_question_display);
```

I get:

```
int(5)
```

But I don't want the `int`. I only want the `5`. In integer form.

If I `foreach` loop the `$group`:

```
foreach ($group as $t) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($t);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I get each of the data as a single data each loop.

```
int(1)
int(1)
string(8) "Novice 1"
string(11) "Lorem Ipsum"
int(5)
NULL
NULL
```

This is obviously also not the way the result accessed that I'm looking for.

I also tried to get the first element of array, thinking that this might be an array with 1 element, but that also raise the same error.

I get it that the general answer in this site about this error is that "stdClass is not array". I have browsed several question with similar title like mine, but nothing address object that came from Laravel DB. When I read the manual on Laravel DB, I was assured that I can access the data returned like a simple dictionary / hashmap.

EDIT: Sorry, I understand my very, very newbie mistakes. No need to answer this. Thanks.

Comment: Doing a `var_dump` gives you the type and the value. `$group->max_question_display` is the right way to go. You can do an `echo` if you are not interested in the type.

Comment: @IbrahimLawal Oh damn. I understand my mistake. That was the result of var_dump. If I access the variable directly, I will get the integer. Sorry. #facepalm

Comment: glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the first line of your first var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#200
```

Because you're dealing with an object, you access its properties with `->`.  When you do:

```
var_dump($group->max_question_display);
```

The reason you see `(int)` in the output is that the `var_dump` function shows the value type, next to the value. To access the value, do

```
$group->max_question_display;
```

If you want to see it on screen without the type, use echo

```
echo $group->max_question_display; // 5
```

Comment: Yes, as soon as I posted this question, it immediately rings a bell in my brain. What a very idiot misunderstanding I made. Thanks. I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm able to.

Comment: @ChenLiYong, it's ok; happens to all of us. Just reminds me that computers have zero understanding of what we're trying to do. they just follow instructions.

Answer (score 1):

stdClass is an object. You cannot use an object with array syntax to access its properties, if the class does not implement [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

As pointed out by @IbrahimLawal , var_dump outputs both the type and value. Just echoing `$group->max_question_display` will provide just the value

```
echo $group->max_question_display; // 5
```

In Summary: You **must**  use arrow syntax when interacting with stdClass.

Comment: I don't think your last sentence is what you meant to type.