# result from data base table

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I m returning data from data base as stdClass, but i wanna use them like in an array... how can i  get to them.

```
public function object($id){
    $result = DB::table("markers")->where("id",$id)->first();
    dd( $result );
    dd( $result["name"] );
    //get_object_vars($result);
    return view('object');

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq432.jpg

and i wanna display the name, like

```
dd( $result["name"] )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" when accessing a clearly existing, integer type data from Laravel Database query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543175/error-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-when-accessing-a-clearly-exi)

Comment: Just do `$result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);`